# Google openid does not ask for consent

Tags: google-authentication, google-openid, google-authenticator, google-openidconnect

i was looking at a website that can identify users using google openId ,

so i login using google , the website got my google profil photo, name and email  but the consent form from google did not show up, how is that possible ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming

Comment: yes she does ..